# Proof verification that Aut$(A_4) \simeq S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I've been watching a video proving $S_4 \simeq$ Aut$(A_4)$, but I was having trouble making sense of it. I wasn't quite sure I even understood exactly what I didn't understand, so I set out to prove it on my own. If I have the core concept down, I'm still unhappy about having to rely on $C_{S_4}(A_4) = \lbrace e \rbrace$ (the centralizer of $A_4$ in $S_4$). It seemed inutitive (which is nice), but I was hoping to rely on something a little more readliy available. Is there a way to easily see the bijection part?

To prove $S_4 \simeq$ Aut$(A_4)$ we need a bijective homomorphism $\alpha: S_4 \rightarrow$ Aut$(A_4)$. Let $\sigma \in S_4$ and define $\alpha(\sigma)=C_\sigma$ where $C_\sigma$ is an autmorphism of $A_4$ defined by $C_\sigma = \sigma h \sigma^{-1}$, $\forall h \in A_4$. We see $C_\sigma$ is an automorphism of $A_4$, since $A_4 \triangleleft S_4$.

First, to show $\alpha$ is a homomorphism: let $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \in S_4$. So, $\alpha(\sigma_1 \sigma_2) = C_{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}$. Then we have, $\forall h \in A_4$, $C_{\sigma_1 \sigma_2}(h)=$

$$\sigma_1 \sigma_2 h (\sigma_{1} \sigma_{2})^{-1}$$
$$= \sigma_1 \sigma_2 h \sigma_{2}^{-1} \sigma_{1}^{-1}$$
$$= \sigma_1 C_{\sigma_{2}}(h) \sigma_{1}^{-1}$$
$$= C_{\sigma_{1}}[C_{\sigma_{2}}(h)]$$
$$= C_{\sigma_{1}} \circ C_{\sigma_{2}} (h) \;.$$

We can now see $\forall h \in A_4$, $C_{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} = C_{\sigma_{1}}  C_{\sigma_{2}}$ so that $\alpha(\sigma_1 \sigma_2) = C_{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} = C_{\sigma_{1}}  C_{\sigma_{2}} = \alpha(\sigma_1) \alpha(\sigma_2)$, and $\alpha$ is a homomorphism.

To see $\alpha$ is bijective, we first note that $\mid$Aut$(A_4)$$\mid \; = a \le 24$ since the generators of $A_4 = \; \lbrace(1 2 3), (1 2)(3 4)\rbrace$  give a total of $8$ choices for the $3$-cycle and $3$ choices for the disjoint transpositions (since generators must preserve order under autmorphisms). As $\mid \;S_4 \mid \; = 24$, if we can show $\alpha$ is one-to-one, then $\alpha$ is a bijection.

To this end, let $k \in$ ker$(\alpha)$. Then $\alpha(k) = C_k$, and $\forall h \in A_4$

$$C_k (h) = khk^{-1} = h$$
$$\implies$$
$$kh=hk\;.$$

But, $C_{S_4}(A_4) = \lbrace e \rbrace$ (the centralizer of $A_4$ in $S_4$), (I got desperate here, so I looked this up), so $k=e$. Since ker$(\alpha)$ is trivial, $\alpha$ is one-to-one, and thus a bijection. From earlier, we also know $\alpha$ is a homomorphism, and so $S_4 \simeq$ Aut$(A_4)$.

Comment: Some general things to keep in mind.
1. We don't __need__ a bijective homomorphism $\alpha : S_4\to \mbox{Aut}(A_4)$, but it certainly suffices to construct one such mapping.
2. For ease of readability, when you define $\alpha$, the image $\alpha (\sigma)$ is a mapping. Define it such that you show to the reader what this mapping does to an element of $A_4$ i.e $\alpha (\sigma) (a) := C_\sigma (a)$ or however it is supposed to work. 

Is $C_G(A_4)$ the center of $A_4$?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was using $C_G(A_4)$ as the centralizer of $A_4$ in $S_4$, or all the elements in $S_4$ that commute with every element in $A_4$. I meant, $C_{S_4}(A_4)$

Comment: One of the comments to the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820704/c-s-4a-4-1?rq=1 has a concise proof of why $C_{S_4}(A_4) = \lbrace e \rbrace$

Comment: Instead of showing that $\alpha$ is one-to-one why not show it is onto?

Comment: Not positive about this, but I think it wouldn't work: $\mid$ Aut$(A_4)$ $\mid $$\; = a \le 24$ and $\alpha$ onto doesn't rule out the possibility of two or more of the automorphisms being the same. It's not true in this case, but if we didn't know exactly what $\sigma$ did, it could be sending them all to the identity automorphism. $a \le 24$ would still be true, and $\alpha$ could be onto. Then Aut$(A_4)$ could be trivial or who knows.

Comment: If you really use the fact that $C_{S_4}(A_4)=1$, then it will be a one-line proof: Since $A_4\unlhd S_4$, $S_4/C_{S_4}(A_4)\cong S_4$ can be embedded in $Aut(A_4)$, but then $|Aut(A_4)|\le24$, so $Aut(A_4)\cong S_4$.