# How powerful is Cayley's theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

So the Cayley's theorem gives a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ for a $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$. So $S_n$ behaves like a Universal set to $G.$

Is there  a smaller universal object for all groups of size $n$?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is 'sometimes'. For example, all groups of order $6$ ($C_6$ and $S_3$) lie in $S_5$, but the quaternion group $Q_8$ of order $8$ requires $S_8$. There are infinitely many $n$ such that there is a group of order $n$ that does not embed in $S_{n-1}$, and infinitely many for which this is not true.

Edit: More easily, cyclic groups of order $p^n$ cannot embed in $S_{p^n-1}$.

But if $n$ is not a prime power then all groups of order $n$ do embed in $S_{n-1}$. To see this, since $G$ does not have order a prime power it is divisible by two primes $p$ and $q$. Then $G$ has an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$, $x$ and $y$ say. The action on the cosets of $\langle x\rangle$ union the action on the cosets of $\langle y\rangle$ yields a (faithful!) embedding of $G$ into a symmetric group of degree $|G|/p+|G|/q<|G|$.

Edit 2: If one just wants a *proper subgroup* of $S_n$ containing all groups of order $n$, then this is always the case for all $n>2$. The only cases that need to be dealt with are $n$ a prime power, as above. But then all $p$-groups are contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup, which has order the $p$-part of $n!$. This is (obviously) much smaller than $n!$.

In general, I (although Nicky Hekster apparently has) have never seen any work on constructing a minimal group containing all groups of order $n$. For $n=6$, for example, this group is the dihedral group $D_{12}$, which is $C_2\times S_3$. This is much smaller than $S_5$, the smallest symmetric group containing both groups of order $6$. If $|G|=p^2$ then this is $C_{p^2}\times C_p$, of order $p^3$.

Comment: You are right that a cyclic group of order $p$ does not embed into $S_{p-1}$. However the universal group for $n=p$ prime is simply $\mathbb{Z}_p$. You can't beat that!

Comment: @freakish Indeed. See paragraph 4 of my answer.

Answer (score 24):

It is probably worth noting that embeddings in symmetric groups of minimal degree have been studied by multiple authors, amongst them, D. L. Johnson, *Minimal permutation representations of finite groups*, Amer. J. Math. **93** (1971), 857-866, D. Wright, *Degrees of minimal embeddings for some direct products*, Amer. J. Math. **97** (1975), 897–903. See also N. Saunders, *Minimal Faithful Permutation Degrees of Finite Groups*, Aust. Math. Soc. Gazette **35**, no.2 (2008), 332-338, and *Strict inequalities for minimal degrees of direct products*, Bull. Aust. Math. Soc. **79**, no.1 (2009), 23–30 by the same author.

Further, and to be complete, I should mention the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313608054_On_minimal_faithful_permutation_representations_of_finite_groups) by David Easdown and Cheryl Praeger, *On minimal faithful permutation representations of finite groups*, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. **38** (1988), 207-220, and a more "recent" [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-minimal-faithful-permutation-representations-of-Kov%C3%A1cs-Praeger/5ba9a42e649f9c9c72d294347a16649a2be7157e) that bears the same title, but was authored by L.G. Kovács and Cheryl Praeger, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. **62** (2000), 311-317.

Finally, in *Minimal embeddings of small finite groups* (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09286) Robert Heffernan, Des MacHale and Brendan McCann determine the groups of *minimal* order in which *all groups of order* $n$ can embedded for $1 \leq n \leq 15$. They further determine the order of a minimal group in which all groups or order $n$ *or less* can be embedded, also for $1 \leq n \leq 15$.

One nice result is the following:
Let $G$ be a group of minimal order in which all groups of order $12$ can be embedded. Then $G \cong S_3 \times S_4$.

Comment: Nice. An OEIS entry turns out to be [A340514](https://oeis.org/A340514), based on Heffernan, MacHale and McCann.

Comment: There are 74 groups of order 256 into which all groups of order 16 embed. (That paper proves that no group of order 128 works.)

Comment: Just an excerpt out of your lastly added resource (Easdown & Praeger): "...The minimal (faithful) degree $μ(G)$ of a finite group $G$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $G ≲ S_n$. Clearly if $H ≤ G$ then $μ(H) ≤ μ(G)$. However if $N ◃ G$ then it is possible for $μ(G/N)$ to be greater than $μ(G)$; such groups $G$ are here called **exceptional**..." (emphasys is mine).

Comment: Yes thanks and this is exceptional indeed, that the minimal degree of a quotient becomes larger than that of the group itself.

Comment: I don't think it's that surprising. The same holds for linear representations. For example the sporadic group $Suz$ embeds in $GL_{143}(\mathbb C)$, whereas $6\cdot Suz$ embeds in $GL_{12}(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Agreed, but it still is counterintuitive.

Comment: (For $16 \leq n\leq 23$, the sequence extends as 256, 17, 216, 19, 160, 63, 44, 23. $n=24$ looks hard. It is greater than $24^2$.)

Answer (score 8):

As a first example of such a "smaller universe", think of any finite $G$ having a proper normal subgroup, $H$. Then, $G$ acts by conjugation on $H$, and the kernel of this action is $C_G(H)$. Therefore, if $C_G(H)$ is trivial, then $G$ embeds into $S_{|H|}$, which is a "smaller universe" than (Cayley's) $S_{|G|}$. For instance, [$C_{S_4}(A_4)=\{1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820704/943729) and hence $S_4\hookrightarrow S_{12}$ (with no claim that this is the *minimal* embedding).

On the contrary, if $|G| = p > m$ is prime, then $p \not\mid |S_m| = m!$. Therefore there cannot be an embedding $G \hookrightarrow S_m$, because its image would be a subgroup of order $p$, contradicting Lagrange's theorem. So, in this case, Cayley's one is the "smallest possible universe".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest example of such a "sharper" (though no claim about its minimality) embedding, is the one of $D_n$ into $S_n$ (which is smaller than Cayley's $S_{2n}$). In fact, with the standard notation for the elements of $D_n$, let $H:=\{1,s\}\le D_{n}$; then, $rHr^{-1}=\{1,r^2s\}$ and hence $H\cap rHr^{-1}=\{1\}$ as soon as $n>2$. This suffices to make the normal core of $H$ in $G$ trivial, and hence the action of $D_n$ on the left quotient set $D_n/H$ (of size $n$) faithful.