Group of order $n$ is a subgroup of $S_{n-1}$
Let $G$ be a group of order $n$, where $n>1$ is not a prime power. Show that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{n-1}$.
I believe I will need to use some form of Cayley's Theorem and/or Cauchy's Theorem, but I am not sure how to make use of these. One possible idea could be letting $n$ have prime factors $p$ and $q$, considering $h$ and $k$ in $G$ with orders $p$ and $q$, and corresponding subgroups $H$ and $K$ generated by these elements, then consider the action of $G$ on the cosets.

I don't understand why this question is getting downvotes and votes to close.

This entry is also worth reading: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269307/how-powerful-is-cayleys-theorem

Yes your idea works exactly as stated. Since $n$ is not a prime power it has distinct prime divisors $p$ and $q$ and subgroups $H$ and $K$.
Let $\phi_H$ and $\phi_K$ be the homomorphisms of $G$ into $S_a$ and $S_b$ arising from the actions of $G$ on the cosets of $H$ and $K$, where $a=|G|/p$ and $b=|G|/q$. So $\ker \phi_H \le H$ and $\ker \phi_K \le K$, and hence $\ker \phi_H \cap \ker \phi_K = \{1\}$.
Now Define $\phi:G \to S_{a+b}$ by letting $\phi(g)$ act as $\phi_H(g)$ on the first $a$ points and as $\phi_B(g)$ on the remaining $b$ points. Then $\phi$ is a homomorphism with kernel $\ker \phi_H \cap \ker \phi_K$, so it is injective, and hence we have an embedding of $G$ into $S_{a+b}$ with $a+b = n/p+n/q < n$, since $1/p+1/q < 1$. So $S_{a+b}$ embeds into $S_{n-1}$ and the result follows.
We have actually proved the slightly stronger result that $G$ embeds into $S_m$ with $m= \lfloor 5n/6 \rfloor$, and neither bound can be improved upon when $G = C_6$ and the smallest possible $m$ is $5$.
(Note that the question is imprecisely worded, and it should really say "Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{n-1}$.")

More generally a group of order $n$ embeds into $S_{n-1}$, with the following exceptions: (1) cyclic of prime power order, (2) generalized quaternion $2$-group, (3) Klein group $C_2 \times C_2$. A relevant reference is D. L. Johnson, Minimal permutation representations of finite groups. Amer. J. Math. 93 (1971), 857--866. See also this question on Mathoverflow
